# Join in salesforce query

Tags: java, android, salesforce, soql

I am using salesforce sdk. I want to fetch records using inner join. I have 2 tables *Campaign* and *Attachment*. Each *Campaign* has a single *Attachment*.

```
SELECT Campaign.CustomerName, Attachment.Body
FROM Campaign
INNER JOIN Attachment
ON Campaign.Id = Attachment.ParentId
```

I'm referring following link. But its not useful i think

https://sivatejaforce.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/a-deeper-look-at-soql-and-relationship-queries/

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I am getting error. with this query

Comment: show us the tables and the columns

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a SQL Query or a SOQL query?

If this is a SOQL query then SQL `JOIN` does not exist.

What you need is:

```
SELECT CustomerName, (SELECT Body FROM Attachments) FROM Campaign
```

This will do a "child" query on a the attachment relationship field.

To give you an example of the return structure for this data as JSON, it would look like this:

```
{
    "CustomerName":"SomeName",
    "Attachments": [ { "Body":"someblob" }, { "Body":"someOtherBlod" } ]
}
```

Comment: If I am using this query. It is returning Didn't understand relationship 'Attachment' in FROM part of query call.

Comment: Salesforce does not join tables. It returns related objects as child properties. In this case attachments would be a property of the Campaign object (a list of attachments). I am not sure how this looks when it is de-serialized in java, however the serialized version(JSON) should look like my example.